# how to draw a block/flow diagram for a code in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a diagram that shows how my program flows.

I have a main routine that calls a few subroutines, which in turn call a few subroutines.

Does a package exist which can show this hierarchy?

I want to be able to configure the size of all the rectangles I draw.

something like this

[image]

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far (there are many, many questions about flow charts on this site, and lots of examples on texample.net). Without a concrete question, this will probably be closed as "too localized".

Comment: If I wouldn't find a package, I was simply going to draw every block individually as a rectangle and then connect them.

Comment: There are some excellent examples in the [TikZ/PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) (perhaps look at the tutorial "Putting a Diagram in Chains" in Section I.5) or also in the [CS area of TeXample.net](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/area/computer-science/) which may be helpful for your case. The node sizes can be easily configured using, e.g., the `text width` and `minimum height` parameters.

Comment: I think this suits nicely - http://texample.net/tikz/examples/family-tree/

Comment: You can draw this easily if you go through "Putting Diagram in Chains" of the `pgfmanual`. There were several methods discussed there. What about trying to do it on your own first then come back here to ask about *the* part that gives you difficulty.